# Why root route not working with users#show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, root

I tried this as my root route `root 'users#show'` so that the User is taken to his profile upon logging in, but instead I'm confronted with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'= 
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

When I use profile as its own tab via, `<li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>` this works, but I can't put `root 'current_user'` or I get this error:

```
ArgumentError
Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.
root 'current_user'
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error message that you've provided points the problem.

If you have root defined as you've mentioned `root "users#show"` it properly executes the `show` action of `UsersController`, but if you have that action implemented "the standard way":

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

it fails here, because there is no `params[:id]`. The value is fetched from url. If you're pointing the url:

```
localhost:3000/users/1
```

the `params[:id]` has value "1".

Because you're trying to point the `root_path`:

```
localhost:3000
```

there is no param `:id` bound, thus:

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

Throws the exception.

If you want to have it "the proper way", modify your *config/routes.rb*:

```
root "users#profile"
get "profile" => "users#profile"
```

and inn your `UserController`:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def profile
    @user = current_user # or any other logic relevant to fetching currently logged in User
  end
end
```

*assuming that you have `current_user` method implemented, and it returns proper `User`*

However, you have to be aware - setting the "profile" as a `root` will cause non-logged in users to see error page.

Hope that helps!

**Update - moving some template to partial**

You can extract the code you need from your *app/views/users/show.html.erb*. Let's say, it's content is something like:

```
<h3><%= @user.name %></h3>
<small><%= @user.bio %></small>
```

You can extract it to partial *app/views/users/_user_details.html.erb*, so it has content:

```
<h3><%= user.name %></h3>
<small><%= user.bio %></small>
```

*Please note, the `@` are removed from here*, and in your *app/views/users/show.html.erb*, you can delete all the code an replace it with:

```
<%= render partial: "user_details", locals: { user: @user } %>
```

The same might be used in your *app/views/pages/home.hmtl.erb* like:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= render partial: "user_details", locals: { user: @user } %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming, in your `PagesController` you have something like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: better explained than me.. as always, Pawel!

Comment: Thanks Pawel! I've been trying to resolve that error issue you mentioned by implementing a conditional. I think I'll keep the root `pages#home`, which then takes me to a form where `<% if logged_in? %> <%= render 'users#show` %> or `users#profile` but then I get an error message because it's not a partial. If I then make it a partial I get another error. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, it is possible! Check my updated answer, so I could include more code snippets! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I've been tinkering with your answer for the past few hours. Finally got it :) Thanks for going above and beyond with the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to redirect him to `show` action and show details of `current user`, then set the `current_user` as `@user`:

```
def show
  @user = params[:id].nil? ? current_user : User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks again SharVy! I don't know if it's possible but I want it where other users can see the profile too so by switching it to current_user wouldn't only the current user be able to see it? Plus adding that line still gave me the first error. Do you think I should just create seperate profiles for the root route and for everyone else?

Comment: Updated my answer, see if helps. Yes, keep the `show` action & view for public view purpose and create another action like `dashboard` for showing self profile.

Comment: I'm afraid the proposed code has one significant downside - if logged in user will try to attempt to visit any other user profile (`/users/1`) he will always see only his data (`current_user` will never be "falsy", thus `User.find(params[:id])` will never be executed).

Comment: @PawełDawczak, you are absolutely right. Updating my answer.

Comment: Sorry SharVy I had to give Pawel the check because although your answer seems right so is his and he helped me move the ball a little further from his update. I hope we can still be friends ;)

Comment: No worries, better answer must be rewarded. :)

Answer (score 0):

The show action is looking for params[:id], but there is no id set during the login.

Try to get the id from your current_user:

```
def show
  params[:id].nil? ? @user = current_user : @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

The condition may help you to get the user's profile when you want to show the profile of other users, as an admin for example.

Comment: Just a little note - `@user` in "second" case will be a `Fixnum` rather than `User` - additional query to `find` `User` would be required. Just saying ;)